# Restsharp - Convert XDocument to Object

Tags: c#, xml, soap, linq-to-xml, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to request that is a simple SOAP services automation project. I load xml via XDocument but, I can't use it in `request.AddBody`.

**Error**: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in RestSharpXML.dll but was not handled in user code

```
 public class SOAPSharp

 {
        XDocument currencyXML = XDocument.Load(@"../../Data/currencyXML.xml");

        [Test]
        public void xmlRequest() {

            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient();

                var request = new RestRequest("http://www.webservicex.net/periodictable.asmx?WSDL", Method.POST);
                request.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer();
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml; charset=utf-8");
               // request.AddBody(ParameterType.RequestBody);
                request.AddBody(currencyXML);

                var response = client.Execute(request);
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) does not implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx).  Instead, use the root [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) which *does* implement `IXmlSerializable`:

```
request.AddBody(currencyXML.Root);
```

Or, just load it as an `XElement` to begin with:

```
var currencyXML = XElement.Load(@"../../Data/currencyXML.xml");
```